# Formal definition of Big-O Notation?

Tags: computer-science

Big O Notation is formally defined as:

> Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be function from positive integers to positive reals. We say $f = \theta(g)$ (which means that "$f$ grows no faster than $g$*)  if *there is a constant $c>0$ such that $f(n) ≤ c ⋅ g(n)$*.

Using this definition how is:

- $n^2 + n$ simplified to $n^2$
- $n + 20$ simplified to $n$

I don't see a $c$ constant that defines their relationship. How do the above examples work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prove that if $n$ is a positive integer then $n^2+n\le2n^2$ and $n+20\le21n$.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, $|f(n)| \le c |g(n)|$ for $n$ sufficiently large. So 
$$|n + 20|\le 2n$$ 
if $n\ge 20$.

Comment: In this case we usually say, "as $n\to\infty$."

Comment: The definition the way OP has given it leaves no room for "sufficiently large".

Comment: If you want for $n\ge 1$, use the last commenter's definition.  If $n=0$, your goose is cooked.

Comment: The finding by the last commenter works if $n \ge 1$ is required.  If you want $n\ge 0$, your goose is cooked.